# With Mercurial (Distributed Version Control), how do we know usernames are not false?

Tags: authentication, mercurial, commit, dvcs, pull

Supposing there were 3 or 4 developers using Mercurial, and all making updates to a project. Right now, usernames are self-configured.

If I pull changes from a colleague, (which may include other changes he pulled from a different colleague), how can I be sure the usernames on each commit actually were authored by that user, and not a different user who might have entered a fake username on that commit?

I assume Mercurial has some solution for this problem built in, perhaps using cryptography to compare the username to the hash and private salt or key or something.

Is there a way to validate authors for each commit? How does this work, and is it possible to do this whilst maintaining the Distributed nature of our Version Control System, or will we need an authenticating server?

Answer (score 0):

You use the [GPG extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GpgExtension).

That means you are using an [OpenPGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) system, and all that entails.

There is a discussion, about the [past, present and future of signing](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommitSigningPlan).